# What's the fastest way to delete all errbit errors from mongodb?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, errbit

I'd like to start over with errbit - there are millions of records in our mongodb database and we hadn't been cleaning them up. I'd like to start over, but I don't want to lose my user accounts.

I've tried to run these routines (https://mensfeld.pl/2015/01/making-errbit-work-faster-by-keeping-it-clean-and-tidy/):

```sh
bundle exec rake errbit:clear_resolved
```

```rb
desc 'Resolves problems that didnt occur for 2 weeks'
task :cleanup => :environment do
  offset = 2.weeks.ago
  Problem.where(:updated_at.lt => offset).map(&:resolve!)
  Notice.where(:updated_at.lt => offset).destroy_all
end
```

but the second one (deleting problems and notices over 2 weeks old), just seems to run forever.
Querying problems and notices collections via mongo shell doesn't seem to show any being deleted... we're using errbit V 0.7.0-dev and mongodb version 3.2.22.

Comment: Seems like a good usecase for [TTL indices](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-ttl/) if it is a single collection. Unfortunately I am not familiar with errbit to provide proper answer. The benefit of the index is it triggers db side so no data exchange, round trips etc.

Answer (score 1):

Fastest way would be to get a mongo console and drop most of the collections. I'd say stop your errbit server, get a mongo console, connect to the db you use and run:

```
> db.errs.drop()
true
> db.problems.drop()
true
> db.backtraces.drop()
true
> db.notices.drop()
true
> db.comments.drop()
```

Answer (score 1):

```rb
Problem.where(:updated_at.lt => 2.months.ago).destroy_all
```

runs too long because of N+1 problem with recursive deletion of Err, Notice and Comment, also mongoid does not support nested eager loading, so only way to delete faster - is to manually take these ids and delete directly, without callbacks:

```rb
problem_ids = Problem.where(:updated_at.lt => 2.months.ago).pluck(:id)
err_ids = Err.where(problem_id: {:$in => problem_ids}).pluck(:id)

Notice.where(err_id:{:$in => err_ids}).delete_all
Err.where(id:{:$in => err_ids}).delete_all
Comment.where(problem_id: {:$in => problem_ids}).delete_all
Problem.where(id: {:$in => problem_ids}).delete_all
```